# process.env.variable is working in local development but after deploying to heroku its not working in nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, heroku, deployment, web-deployment, nuxt.js

I am using nuxt.js and trying to show images dynamically. That's why I use BASE_URL variable inside .env file and access image files according to the BASE_URL in my local environment.

*.env file*

```
BASE_URL = https://pctool.herokuapp.com
DB_HOST = dummy_host_name
DB_USER = dummy_user_name
DB_NAME = dummy_database_name
PASSWORD = dummy_password
```

*in image.vue file*

template

```
 <img class="pic-0" :src="makeImagePath(product.image[0])"/>
```

script

```
methods: {
    makeImagePath (img_name) {
      return process.env.BASE_URL + "/product/" + img_name;
    }
}
```

Local output is
[image: image showing with proper url]

But after deploy the code to Heroku is not working with env variable.

**heroku env**

[heroku env veariables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5MBR.png)

Deployed output is

[image: image is not showing and url is also not proper]

But if I make the URL hardcoded like below
script

```
methods: {
    makeImagePath (img_name) {
      return  "https://pctool.herokuapp.com/product/" + img_name;
    }
}
```

Then it's working both places. Now in that position URL is not dynamic, I have to change the URL from local to production wherever I use that concept in my project. That's why I want to make the URL dynamic so that there was no conflict during deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you should not commit your `.env` file. In your Heroku app under settings you can set the environment variables.

[image]

There you can define these again:

```
BASE_URL = https://pctool.herokuapp.com
DB_HOST = dummy_host_name
DB_USER = dummy_user_name
DB_NAME = dummy_database_name
PASSWORD = dummy_password
```

Comment: i have added like you said but its still not working and giving same probleam.

Comment: I am having the same problem they are added there but not red in build phase

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. If you want to access .env variables client side, you need to define them in the Heroku Config Vars settings, but then you also need to add this inside your nuxt.config.js file, for example:

```
publicRuntimeConfig: {
    baseUrl: process.env.BASE_URL,
    originHeader: process.env.ORIGIN_HEADER
}
```

Then you'll be able to access them like this: `this.$config.baseUrl`

Of course, be sure you do not expose any private variables like API keys or whatever in this way, as these are client-side and therefore public. Cheers!